# Change Info Window of markers of a list of Places

Tags: android, window

this is my first post.
I have an ArrayList of Places that I need to mark on my map.
I use a for loop to go through each place and add a marker to the map.
But I need to change the info window of the markers.

I'm using this code.

```
for (j = 0; j < result.size()-1; j++) {

    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            View myContentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custommarker, null);
            TextView tvTitle = ((TextView) myContentView.findViewById(R.id.title));
            tvTitle.setText(result.get(j).getName());
            TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView) myContentView.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
            tvSnippet.setText(result.get(j).getVicinity());
            TextView tvPrice = ((TextView) myContentView.findViewById(R.id.price));
            tvPrice.setText("Price: $100.00");
            return myContentView;
        }
    });

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .title(result.get(j).getName())
        .position(new LatLng(result.get(j).getLatitude(), result.get(j).getLongitude()))
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icone))
        .snippet(result.get(j).getVicinity()));
}
```

But it always returns the getName and getVicinity of the last result into every marker.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to post value of `result` ArrayList in Logcat.

Comment: I did, it returns all the correct places I marked on the map. The marker are all there in the map, but when I click the marker, the info window of all the markers are the same.

Comment: You need to set InfoWindowAdapter in the map only once. But you are setting it several times.Check [this](http://androidfreakers.blogspot.in/2013/08/display-custom-info-window-with.html) tutorial.

Comment: I tried wrapping only the addMarker in the for loop, but the result is the same.

Comment: I found the problem, intead of result.get(j).getName(), I should use marker.getTitle(). Thanks for your help.